# Responisve Divs (already positoned)

Tags: html, css, responsive

I made a marksheet generator. The resulting page has an image with a z-index=-1 and all the divs are positioned over the image. However, it looks fine when viewing it normally in the browser, but when I click "print" the positioned divs are not responsive and some bizarre print preview is displayed. How to make the already positioned divs responsive?

For example how can I make the following div responsive?
HTML

```css
#name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17.4%;
  left: 31%;
}

#cl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18%;
  left: 58%;
}
```

```html
<div id="name">
  <font size="3" face="courier new"><b><%out.print(name);%>  </b></font>
</div>

<div id="cl">
  <font size="2" face="courier new"><b> -<%out.print(cl);%></b></font>
</div>
```

Comment: I am stuck at this problem for many days. need help. Thank you!

Comment: the font tag is obsolete and should not be used - and you probably want to change the b tag for a strong tag

Comment: i will mind this from now on. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to understand how positioning work in css and here's the quick link for it: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Secondly all your absolute child need to be inside of relative parent div.

Something like this:

```
<div class="relative_parent">
  <div id="name">
    <font size="3" face="courier new"><b><%out.print(name);%>  </b></font>
  </div>

  <div id="cl">
    <font size="2" face="courier new"><b> -<%out.print(cl);%></b></font>
  </div>
</div>

.relative_parent{
  position: relative;
}

#name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17.4%;
  left: 31%;
}

#cl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18%;
  left: 58%;
}
```

What this does is whenever there's an pixel changed for parent div it's inner child will also move along with its parent.

> Quick Tip:
>   Never use ID's for styling in css use them in JS they have the higher specificity then classes and gives problem if modified by using different modifier.

Comment: Thank You sooooo much it worked. I was stuck here for soo long! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You give a terrible tip (about the ids), by all means use a class, but I always use ids if I want to overwrite specific instances of a class.  In this case, I don't see the position being re-used for multiple elements so ID would be fine